# mooflow overlapping images

Tags: mootools

I am using one of mootools plugins, called Mooflow. Everything works fine, except overlapping image issue.

http://mootools-users.660466.n2.nabble.com/Moo-Problem-with-Mooflow-td3174068.html

I have a exact same issue with above link.

has anyone figured it out?

THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be only a css problem, you have to take care of the z-index that is being applied to.
Try to use the firebug tool for firefox to find out what the problem is